# How can I get the region where a row is located using its ID?

Tags: java, hbase

If I have a row with ID = "my_row_id", how can I use "my_row_id" to get the region where this row is when using Hbase's Java API? (the code I am writing will run on each region server)

I found examples like this:

```
   for (JVMClusterUtil.RegionServerThread t : util.getMiniHBaseCluster().getLiveRegionServerThreads()) {
      for (HRegionInfo r : t.getRegionServer().getOnlineRegions()) {
        if (!Arrays.equals(r.getTableDesc().getName(), "my_table"))) {
          continue;
        }

        HRegion region = t.getRegionServer().getOnlineRegion(r.getRegionName());
      }
   }
```

But *util.getMiniHBaseCluster()* seems to be from a test utility, How would I get a "real" instance of *JVMClusterUtil.RegionServerThread* on a region server?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run code on every region server to find where row is located.

HBase table has splits, which partition data across the nodes in cluster. This is meta information used by HBase master. It's available in api too:

```
HTable table = new HTable(configuration, tableName);
RegionLocator regionLocator = table.getRegionLocator();
HRegionLocation location = regionLocator.getRegionLocation(myRow);

String host = location.getHostname();
```

Comment: Thanks @adamskywalker, if its a case where I'm modifying a plugin that needs to run on every region server, is there any other way to check if the row is located on each server?

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno I can't suggest anything because the code you attached seems to be used for test standalone server, not real hbase server

Comment: understood, what I want is a HRegion instance (or variable?) by only knowing the row id (and table name) using the code that will run on each region server

Comment: for example, HRegion region = _get_region_of_row(my_row_id)_

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno HRegion class is annotated with InterfaceAudience.Private, are you sure you need to access it? It seems to be internal HBase class

Comment: That comment "knocked" some sense into me, I dont need none of the code in my question. What I should've asked was: do I need _LuceneCoprocessor c = RegionCPHost.findCoprocessor(LuceneCoprocessor.class.getName());_ which is in the test code or just _LuceneCoprocessor c;_ to access a  Coprocessor or is there another (better/correct?) way to do it.